# C#, is there such a thing as a "thread-safe" stream?

Tags: c#, multithreading, stream, thread-safety

I am redirecting the output of a process into a streamreader which I read later. My problem is I am using multiple threads which SHOULD have separate instances of this stream. When I go to read this stream in, the threading fudges and starts executing oddly. 
Is there such a thing as making a thread-safe stream?
 **EDIT:** I put locks on the ReadToEnd on the streamreader, and the line where I did:    reader = proc.StandardOutput;

Comment: What does "threading fudges and starts executing oddly" mean?

Comment: You may implement your own thread safe read/write operations using a lock. It is simple and easy.

Comment: Fudging: Starts executing consecutively and sometimes miss interpreting data.

Comment: can, Would I do lock(process.StandardOutput){} to lock the writing?

Comment: Based on the original question Mark's answer is spot on. Maybe if there were other mitigating circumstances you can note them.

Answer (score 22):

There's a SyncrhonizedStream built into the framework, they just don't expose the class for you to look at/subclass etc, but you can turn any stream into a SynchronizedStream using

```
var syncStream = Stream.Synchronized(inStream);
```

You should pass the syncStream object around to each thread that needs it, and make sure you never try to access inStream elsewhere in code.

The SynchronizedStream just implements a monitor on all read/write operation to ensure that a thread has mutually exclusive access to the stream.

**Edit:**

Appears they also implements a SynchronizedReader/SynchronizedWriter in the framework too.

```
var reader = TextReader.Synchronized(process.StandardOutput);
```

Comment: Stream.Synchronized cannot be called on a streamreader which is what you get from Process.StandardOutput.

Comment: This compiled correctly, however it is doing the same thing it did before.

Comment: Does anybody know why there is no Stream.Synchronized() in PCL?

Comment: @AlexanderLogger A bit late, but for anyone looking: I presume this is due to facilities like Mutex not being available on certain framework subsets.