# Can't Use Stream.Write method while playing same file in MediaElement

Tags: c#, stream, filestream, streamwriter, mediaelement

So lets say I have a file which has around 2MB already downloaded and written which is being played using a MediaElement. So while the media is being played, I want to download and write the rest of the file.
If I use this method, I get an IOExecption error indicating the file is already in use.

```
 using (Stream WriteStream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
      {
        WriteStream.Seek(seekpos, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        WriteStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        WriteStream.Close();
      }
```

But if I use this method, it works fine.

```
FileStream1 = new System.IO.FileStream(filename, System.IO.FileMode.Append, System.IO.FileAccess.Write, System.IO.FileShare.ReadWrite);
FileStream1.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
```

So I could use the second method, but I want to be able to seek and write at certain positions which I can't do using the second method. So is there anyway in which I can use the first method. Does it have something to do with the FILEMODE or FILEACCESS? 
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never-mind I figured it out. I can use this to seek and write at any position. Stupid of me to not realise this.

```
FileStream1 = new System.IO.FileStream(filename, System.IO.FileMode.Append, System.IO.FileAccess.Write, System.IO.FileShare.ReadWrite);
FileStream1.Seek(seekpos,SeekOrigin.Begin);
FileStream1.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
```

Answer (score 0):

The closest you might get might be displayed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6819581/c-is-there-such-a-thing-as-a-thread-safe-stream) with what's known as a synchronized stream.  Essentially, it's multiple threads acting on the same stream.  You'd have to get the locking issue resolved, especially since you may have no way of making the MediaElement open the file with a shared lock.

Another approach might be to write to one file while the MediaElement plays from another.  When the MediaElement's done with file A, play B and stream downloads to new file C.  Repeat.  Then, at the end, merge them together.